# AngularJs $resource save throwing ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

Tags: node.js, angularjs

Using AngularJs $resource for updating the existing data. calling save on resource.

This is my service.

```
app.factory('SubscriptionsService', function ($resource, $q) {
    // $resource(url, [paramDefaults], [actions], options);
    var resource = $resource('/api/subscriptions');
    var factory = {};

    factory.updateSubscriptions = function (updatedSubscriptions) {
        console.log("SubscriptionsService: In updateSubscriptions. "+JSON.stringify( updatedSubscriptions));
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        resource.save(updatedSubscriptions,
            function(response){
                deferred.resolve(response);    
            },
            function(response){
                deferred.reject(response); 
            }
        );
        return deferred.promise;
    }
    return factory;
});
```

And API looks like the following.

```
exports.update = function (req, res) {
    console.log("In Subscriptions API: Update invoked.");
    if (req.body == null || req.body.items == null || req.body.items == 'undefined') {
        return res.json({"status":0,"message":"no items present."});
    }
    var items = req.body.items;
    console.log("About to call update on db."+items);
    db.update(items,function(error,result,failedItems){
        if(error)
            return res.json({"status":-1,"message":error.message,"failedItem":failedItems});

        return res.json({"status":1,"message":result,"failedItem":failedItems});
    })
}
```

And controller as follows

```
$scope.confirmUpdates = function () {
        if ($scope.updatedItems.length > 0) {
            var updatedSubscriptionLevels = { "items": $scope.updatedItems };
            var promise = SubscriptionsService.updateSubscriptions(updatedSubscriptionLevels);
            promise.then(
                function(response){
                    console.log("Response received from API.");
                    var statusCode = response.status;
                    console.log("statusCode: "+statusCode);
                },
                function(message){
                    console.log("Error message: "+message);
                }
            );
        }
}
```

Strange part is data is getting updated. But promise receiving an error.

*POST xxxxxx/testapi/subscriptions net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH*

I doubt I am not implementing/consuming resource in a right way. Can anybody advise?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the mistake.

There were couple of things I was not handling in a right way.

I didn't post my db code in mt question where the root cause was present.

```
if(itemsToUpdate!=null && itemsToUpdate.length>0){
            var failedItems = []; // Holds failed items while updating.
            console.log("Items to update: "+itemsToUpdate);
            for(var index=0;index<itemsToUpdate.length;index++){
                var item = itemsToUpdate[index];
                console.log(item);
                subscriptionLevels.update(
                    {_id:item._id},
                    {$set:{title:item.title,daysValid:item.daysValid,subscriptionFee:item.subscriptionFee}},
                    function(error,rowsEffected){
                        if(error){
                            console.log(error);
                            // Error occurred. Push it to failed items array.
                            failedItems.push({"title":item.title,"message":error.message});
                        }
                        else{
                            console.log("Number of rows updated: "+rowsEffected);
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
            callback(null,"SUCCESS",failedItems);
        }
        else {
            callback(null, "NO_ITEMS", []);
        }
```

I missed if - else condition and invoking callback multiple times which was causing the issue.